# Why my mustache edges becomes poke after shaving my beard?

Tags: facial-hair, pluck-plucking, shave-shaving, shaving-cream, aftershave

I shave my beard with the help of body soap (I wont use shaving cream)
& I won't shave my mustache, but the left & right side of mustache becomes very pointy after I finish shaving. So I created a habit of plucking the edges of my mustache on both ends of lips at nights and by morning it will look like a hitler type mustache.

What causing this weird problem?